# What does "min(X(X>0), Y, Z)" mean in Python?

Tags: python

There is a statement written in Python and I am not able to understand what that particular line means.

Statement is:

```
signal = -16
powerRating = 30
energyRating = 30
socHigh = 1
soc = 15
freq = 15
chargeEff = 0.93
answer = min(signal*(signal>0), powerRating, (energyRating*socHigh - soc)*60.0/dataFreq/chargeEff),0)
```

In the answer statement there is written

```
signal(signal > 0)
```

What does this mean?

Comment: No, it's `signal*(signal>0)`. Which multiplies `signal` (`-16`) with the result of `signal>0`, which is either `True` or `False`, which happen to correspond to `1` or `0`.

Comment: Can you provide us with more context? `signal > 0` seems an expression that evaluates to a Boolean Value (that in Python is a "special" Integer type equal to `0` or `1`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the expression

```
signal*(signal>0)
```

`signal>0` is True if `signal` is positive and False otherwise. True is 1 and False is zero. So if you multiply `signal` by `signal>0`, you get `signal` if `signal` is positive, otherwise zero.

It's a more confusing way of writing

```
max(signal, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

`(signal>0)` evaluates to `1` when the condition is true, and `0` otherwise.  The multiplication thus causes any negative values to be zeroed (multiplication with zero yields zero) and others to go through unchanged (multiplication with one yields identity).

Answer (score 0):

In Python, a True value corresponds to 1, and a False value corresponds to 0. `signal > 0` will either be True, or False, and will have a 1 or 0 value accordingly. `signal * (signal > 0)` simply returns the value of signal, if it is True; otherwise returns 0. It can be seen as

```
if signal < 0:
  signal = 0
```

Adding the above piece if code does the same work as `signal * (signal > 0)`, as if the `if` condition is False, the signal value remains unaltered.